# How to remove stratified line and legends from this plot figure

Tags: r, plot

I'm using a function called maplot from edgeR package. I think this package is based on the innate plot function. Here's the plot I ended up getting.

[image]

My question is, if I want to remove legend and the lines in the lpot, what parameter should I include in the function?

Answer (score 0):

> swirl.norm <- maNorm(swirl[,3], methods = "Median")

> maPlot(swirl.norm, legend.func = NULL, lines.func = NULL, main = "MvA Plot of Normalized Array Without Stratified Lines or Legend")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).